# Subject + (to be) + adjective + to + verb

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is correct?

1. I am easy to deceive.
2. I am easy to be deceive.

Comment: The first one correct. The second one is incorrect because you don't get or be deceived, but you are deceived, which means that all you need is 'I am easy to deceive.'

Answer (score 0):

1 is correct. Although you are having the action done to you, the construction still uses an active infinitive.

Comment: "The pill is easy to swallow" is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.